# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Tags: pandas, list

```
import numpy as np
def answer_seven():
    counties = census_df[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011','POPESTIMATE2012','POPESTIMATE2013','POPESTIMATE2014','POPESTIMATE2015']]
return counties[[counties.max(axis=1)]-[counties.min(axis=1)]].abs().idxmax()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Above is my code which does not work and I got this error message.

But the code below does work.

```
import numpy as np
def answer_seven():
    counties_df = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50][['CTYNAME','POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011','POPESTIMATE2012','POPESTIMATE2013',
                                                       'POPESTIMATE2014','POPESTIMATE2015']]
    counties_df["MaxDiff"] = abs(counties_df.max(axis=1) - counties_df.min(axis=1))
    most_change = counties_df.sort_values(by=["MaxDiff"], ascending = False)
    return most_change.iloc[0][0]
```

It uses max and min function to get the max difference as well which uses a list to subtract another list. Could someone explain to me why my code is not working but this one does? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, You can format your code as code by indenting it with 4 spaces. That would help in readability

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here -

```
return counties[[counties.max(axis=1)]-[counties.min(axis=1)]]
```

You are subtracting two lists, I think the below edit should make it work

```
return counties[counties.max(axis=1)-counties.min(axis=1)]
```